# SQL to Extract XML Clob Causes Oracle 10g Database to Freeze Up

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle10g

I need help figuring out why my database server crashes when I perform the following query:

```
SELECT T.COLLECTION_ID, T.CYCLE_ID, T.PHASE_ID, EXTRACT(T.XML_DOCUMENT, '/') 
FROM THINGS T
WHERE T.COLLECTION_ID = 1668 AND T.CYCLE_ID = 26601 AND T.DELETED = 0 
ORDER BY T.COLLECTION_ID, T.CYCLE_ID, T.PHASE_ID
```

Additional details:

- The CLOB in the above XML_DOCUMENT column for this record is 780kb
- The database is Oracle 10g
- The XML in the CLOB is well-formed

If there is nothing obvious in the PLSQL above that can be changed to avoid freezing up the database, does anyone have any ideas on how/if I could tweak my server or database to avoid crashes from these types of queries in general?

Any potential solutions or advice is highly valued, thanks!

Comment: Do you really mean crash or some kind of ORA-XXXXX error

Comment: Crash.  As a result, other calls to the database after the crash get the following errors:

 ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure and ORA-03135: connection lost contact.  We also get "ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted" when the database is shutdown by our DBAs as a result, but that is superfluous to the issue.

Comment: Is this XML document unusually complex compared to other documents you've processed?  Can you extract the XML document as text and try to parse it through some other XML parser?  Perhaps the document is malformed in some way that renders it unprocessable.

Comment: I can "pretty-print" the XML from UltraEdit and other XML editors, so it seems to be well-formed XML, if that's what you mean.  The XML has a lot of repetitive namespace references in it, but removing them would only be a temporary solution if the issue is size.  I just wanted to see if there were PLSQL alternatives or database tweaks that could be applied to stop the server from using up so much CPU to run the above statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Oracle 11g has solved our issue.  11g handles XML operations more efficiently than 10g, and handles faults a lot better too.

[Another person on Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=555162) has made a similar conclusion using different XML operations, so it's probably safe to assume the upgrade was the appropriate solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You (or your DBA) need to look at the alert log and trace files for details of what is happening.  Any catastrophic Oracle error *should* write a trace file for the process that crashes.

Also check you NLS settings / DB character sets at all levels; I once had a situation with some superficial similarity to your description which I resolved by changing the DB character set.

What happens if another user (OS and DB user) on another machine tries the same query?

Have the DBA check for block corruption.  Dump out the DB block and check for odd characters.

And please let us know what you find; this is interesting to me.

Comment: Thanks, these are some great suggestions.  To answer your question: It happens for other users who run the same statement remotely on other machines.

Comment: Can the DBA make a two-tier connection to the database?  This would help to identify whether it is connections via the listener that is the issue.  What happens if after encountering the issue the Listener rather the DB is rebooted?

Comment: We finally figured it out.  It seems upgrading to Oracle 11g solves the issue... 11g seems to handle the command a little better.  We were copying the problematic XML into 11g for testing and got this error: IMP error 63 on "ArrayOfSelectedRecordLe1818_T" ... finally the DBA was able to copy the data, and the above PLSQL no longer caused an issue.  So the answer is "Oracle 11g handles XML better" - vague, but an answer all the same.